Increasing height of walkout basement door to meet code requirements?
Looking to try and increase the height of our walkout basement door from 74" to 78" to meet building code requirements. I'm currently looking at getting rid of the rid of the step at the threshold which should add at least a couple inches. Inside the basement, there is currently drop ceiling which I am planning to get rid of for drywall, which will solve the problem of interior clearance. Any other ideas on how this may be accomplished? I'm wondering if the head jamb casing may be made even shorter or entirely removed to also facilitate this. I'd like to avoid cutting into the stucco if possible because there may be support beams in place, as the top of the door appears to be roughly where the foundation meets the house (not sure about this as there's quite a bit more ceiling height beyond the top of the door). Does anyone have any ideas on how this may be accomplished ?

This is a job that you need to remove some stuff to see how hard it will be.  Drywall can hide stuff, but removing it is easy.  Once you can see, it might be easy(only wood to change) or hard(foundation on top).  Once you can see, we might help with pictures you take.

You might want to check if the current threshold prevents water from flowing into the basement.  Lowering it may introduce a slope that goes the wrong way.
